# Referencing Cytoscape elements from external code

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to integrate qTip2 to show tooltips on mouse events for elements in a Cytoscape graph. I'm using [this example](http://jsbin.com/gist/546dd8ca4872cc87106a?js,output). However, in my testing, the attempt to call qtip() on the selected element object fails, and IE for example says object doesn't support property or method qtip. I am sure the selector is working, since I can get at all of the element's properties.

What am I missing? Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
cy.getElementById("n1").qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'My tooltip text'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, which is that there is a separate extension for qTip in this case, which I didn't see from looking at the JS Bin example. You can get the extension [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip).